# Is there a way to retrieve Google Analytics 4 data on a schedule using Node.js?

Tags: python, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-api-js-client

This is what I want to achieve:

1. Ask the user to authorize the collection of their data on a Google Analytics 4 property (or Universal Analytics but I would rather not)
2. Programmatically retrieve and store the data every n-hours

I was able to do (1) client-side by asking for authorization with google's OAUTH2 and making a call to Reporting API v4 https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4 using gapi on the front-end.

However, I'm not sure how to do it on a schedule without user interaction. I've searched Google's API docs and I believe there's a way to do it in python https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py but I am currently limited to Node and the browser. I guess I could make a server in python that does the data fetching and connects with the Node application, but that's yet another layer of complications that I'm trying to avoid. Is there a way to do everything in Node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCP APIs are all documented in a way which allows everyone to generate client libraries in a variety of languages, including node.js. The documentation for the node.js client for Analytics Reporting is [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/analyticsreporting/index.html).

For the question of how to schedule this on GCP, I would recommend you to use Cloud Scheduler. This will hit an endpoint running on Cloud Run, which will do the actual work. Alternatively, if you already have a service running somewhere else, you can simply add the required endpoints there and point Cloud Scheduler to it.

The overall design which I would suggest you goes something like this:

- Build a site which takes the user through the OAUTH2 login process,
  requesting the relevant Google Analytics Reporting API scopes
  required to make the request.
- Store the obtained credentials in their user database.(preferably
  [Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore) in Datastore mode)
- Set up a [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run) service (or anything else), with two endpoints
- Iteration endpoint: Iterate through the list of users and add tasks
  to [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks) to hit the download endpoint for each one.
- Download endpoint: Takes a user ID (e.g. as a query parameter) and
  performs the download for this user. You will need to load the
  credentials for the user from the database and use this to access the
  reporting API.
- Store the downloaded data in the desired location, e.g. [Cloud
  Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage), Firestore, [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql), etc.
- Set up [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler) to hit the iteration endpoint at the desired
  frequency.

For the GCP services mentioned above, basically everything other than Analytics, you may use the "cloud" clients for node.js, which are available [here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference)

**Note** : The question you have asked is a very broad question and this answer is just a suggestion. You may think about other designs whichever works best for you.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for !